# Identify all tokens/words which end with a specific character (#) using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, pattern-matching

I've been thru about 6+ hours of internet trawling to try and figure out the following:

1. I need a javascript regex expression which identifies that the `#` character is at the end of the token.
2. The token delimiter is an empty space
3. I have the following Regex: `/(\w+[#])/ig`
   3a. The issue with the above Regex is that it will return `99999#` AND `999#` and `a#dfkjdf#dfd#` (where the hash is in the midst of a string/token
4. The test data looks like this as a string of text:
   `#78890 _1ASBCJH- #78890 999 #werer 99999# today? 999#999 a#dfkjdf#dfd#f`
5. So the result set should be `9999#` only for above
6. for test data like this:
   `#78890 _1ASBCJH- #78890 999 #werer 99999# 999#999 today# a#dfkjdf#dfd#f`
7. The result set should be:
   `99999# today#`

The reason behind the request is that our application has a 'reject' keywords function so I want to reject all tokens/words which end in `#`, for example UPS `09870#` (which could be a UPS office location, I just want UPS).

Our application also has an 'accept' function (based on Regex) which would keep the UPS value.

PS - I have the regex to test for the word/token starting with a `#` which is as follows: `/(^|\s)#(-|\w+)/ig`

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: sorry for the formatting, the numbers were supposed to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use a regex at all, they're overkill for this task.

```
function accept(s) {
    return s.split(' ').filter(x => x.endsWith('#'));
}
```

The result will be an array of the matching words.   Add `.join(' ')` to the end of the chain if you want a string containing the list instead.

Comment: Using `endsWith()` is really better than a regex, nice approach.

Comment: @chŝdk  it also has the advantage of being insensitive to characters that don't match `\w`.

Comment: Yes, indeed it's 100% safe to use it, no matter what are the characters before the #, you beat me to it ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately it must be a regex expression.

Comment: @AndyS why?  If this is an artificial constraint (e.g. because it's homework) you should have said so.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
/(?:^|\s)\w+#(?!\S)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7hdRiZ/1).

**Details**

- `(?:^|\s)` - start of string or whitespace
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `#` - a `#` char
- `(?!\S)` - whitespace or end of string required right after `#`.

JS demo:

```js
console.log(
  "#78890 _1ASBCJH- #78890 999 #werer 99999# 999#999 today# a#dfkjdf#dfd#f"
    .match(/(?:^|\s)\w+#(?!\S)/g)
    .map(function(x) { return x.trim(); })
)
```

Or, if you only plan to support ECMAScript 2018 compliant environments, you may use a lookbehind-powered pattern, `/(?<!\S)\w+#(?!\S)/g`, where `(?<!\S)` requires a whitespace or start of string immediately to the left of the current location:

```js
console.log("#78890 _1ASBCJH- #78890 999 #werer 99999# 999#999 today# a#dfkjdf#dfd#f"
        .match(/(?<!\S)\w+#(?!\S)/g)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `split()` and `filter()` methods along with **[the `/\w+#$/g` regex](https://regex101.com/r/lIgxY8/1)**, to get the desired results:

```
str.split(" ").filter(v => v.match(/\w+#$/));
```

**Demo:**

This is a working demo:

```js
var str = "#78890 _1ASBCJH- #78890 999 #werer 99999# today# 999#999 a#dfkjdf#dfd#f";

var results = str.split(" ").filter(v => v.match(/\w+#$/));
console.log(results);
```

Comment: p.s. the `/g` qualifier on your regex is redundant.

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, well pointed out, I was just copying it from the regex101 where I was testing. Thank you ;)

Comment: you could of course make this "safe" re: other characters just by completely omitting the `\w+` from the regex, i.e. `v.match(/#$/)`.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, that's true, although the OP never explicitly defined what a token is.   My `.endsWith()` solution technically has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Something I just tried as a solution as well:
\b(\w+)*[#]\B